# DVR/NVR device to connect various analog cameras

Tags: video-camera, video-capture

We are cosolidating  video surveillance systems on our sites.

I am 
looking for an IP enabled DVR/NVR device that would be capable of handling video signal from 
different CCTV BNC analog cameras (presumably all PAL) with different 
resolutions CIF, DCIF etc., till max 720 x 480. from different manufacturers (Avir,
 Pixim, JCC, Sony, Trans Pac, Tekno, Hikvision, CP Plus etc.).

The device 
should be also able to connect IP ONVIF cameras and work as NVR as we switch to IP cameras continuously.

Also it should be possible to connect to multiple sites over IP 
network with one user-friendly interface or application with password protection and various access levels (separate access rights to view recordings and change settings). It would be nice if it allows 
for streaming individual cameras form our custom windows .NET app.
Also the device must be capable of deleting recordings older than X days and perform network time sync.

Usually there are max. 8 cameras on sites, on some others up to 16.

So far the [DAHUA S3 or NT](http://www.dahuasecurity.com/products/hcvr82088216a-s3-2211.html) looks promising, but I have no hands on experience with it so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like normal older analog CCTV cameras pose no significant problem, they function basically the same regardless on manufacturer.

The problem arises with HD-SDI, HD-TVI, HD-CVI, AHD formats and IP cameras and different levels of built-in ONVIF support.

http://www.supercircuits.com/lp/compare-hd-analog-video-formats

So I have chosen

[HIKVISION DS-7208/16HQHI-F2/N](http://www.hikvision.com/en/Products_accessries_364_i5792.html) or similar, because it supports analog, AHD and HD-TVI cameras and a range of ONVIF IP cameras too. (Checked it with a new AVTECH IP camera and worked ok).

Dashua DVRs support different standard HD-CVI, so it is a matter of choice. HD-SDI cameras are generally a problem. Dashua has better versatility because their hybrid DVRs allow for connecting more IP cameras than HIKVISION. I like Dashua playback interface better, but some functions like setting expired time for streams work better on HIKVISION. Dashua does not allow setting auto deleting old records per stream, HIKVISION does.

Other relevant manufacturers like PINETRON do not offer those hybrid DVR models or I have not found it.